# How can I stretch a div within a table within a div to the remainder of the page's height?

Tags: html, css

Having been working on a website that uses a single page layout with buttons that actively alter the content in a single div, I have become stuck on how to fix one formatting issue that I have. Namely, I would like to be able to stretch the content in div id="CTR1" in the bottom most table to the bottom of the page, leaving only space for the footer, thus sticking it to the bottom as well. I have approached this problem with various tricks such as Ryan Fait's sticky footer, but all to no avail. I have commented the code such that it is easier to read.

"How can I stretch the div "CTR1" to the bottom of the page leaving space only for the 25px footer?"

I am working with some code that I have laid out in the following format:

Original Code at: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynqcm6mu/)

```
<body style="font-family:'gloria hallelujah', cursive; height:100%;">

  <header style="background:IMAGES/white.jpg;"></header>

  <!-- This is just an image that will bring back to homepage -->

  <div align="center"><a href="http://www.swirlndipity.com"><img src="IMAGES/Swirlndipity-Logo-Main.png" width="500" height="136" alt="Swirlndipity" /></a></div>

  <!-- A table that contains clickable columns alter center content -->

  <table width="800px" border="0" cellpadding="5" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
    <tr style="text-align:center">
      <!-- table content, 7 columns "<td>" with 10px padding -->
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- The following div acts as a container for a table that contains content -->

  <div style="background-color:#00bde4; margin-top:10; margin-left:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:10;">

    <!-- this table contains the content, it is the one that I wish to stretch to the remainder of the page. -->

    <table width="800" border="0" cellpadding="10" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:10; margin-bottom:10; max-width:800; min-width:800; height:100%;">
      <tr>         
        <td align="left" background="IMAGES/white.png">
          <div id="CTR1" style="background-color:#FFF; margin-top:10; margin-bottom:10; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            <!-- CONTENT -->
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

    <!-- The footer -->

  <div id="BTM1" style="position:relative; min-width:100%; font-size:9px; text-align:left; height:25px;">        
    <hr>
    <img src="IMAGES/image1" height="25" width="25"/></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would be easier to help debug if you made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) :)